# Laravel 5.5 api calls using passport going to web routes instead of api

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am building an api into an existing laravel application. I followed the tutorial in the docs adn using postman I am trying to call an endpoint but keep getting pushed into my web.php routes. In there I have the following at the bottom:

```
Route::get('{catchall}', ['as' => 'url', 'uses'=>'PagesController@getPage'])->where('catchall', '(.*)');
```

Which catches all the pages that do not have routes and sends them to a 404 page. The api calls are getting to that route and returning the 404. Why are they not hitting the api.php file first?

Comment: how do you call your route in postman using url?

Comment: you need to add api prefix in url to call api.php

Comment: @pal you were correct. for some reason I have to do http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/api and now it works. Post this as the answer and I will accept in case someone else gets here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add api prefix in url to call api.php, like if you have home route in api.php then call it like:

```
Http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login
```

Answer (score 1):

First, test your API endpoints using POSTMAN.

Request URL should be something like http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/login. **Remember /api/ in the path**

Use `Accept:application/json` in request header.

[image]